# Unable to use if statement in volley onresponse method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Here is my PHP code, when I want to do a custom method if (string equals to success) but it doesn't work. without if this method returning a string value of response. I want to just do some method if response give success

```
<?php
    define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.in');
    define('USER','example');
    define('PASS','example');
    define('DB','example');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

    $username = $_POST['PHONENO'];
    $password = $_POST['PASSWORD'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Prago WHERE PHONENO='$username' and PASSWORD='$password'";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    if(isset($check)){
    echo 'success';
    }else{
    echo 'failure';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my volley string request class

```
   StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.equals("success")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DONE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"check username and password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            callback.onSuccess(response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"error in volley",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
            map.put("PHONENO",Number);
            map.put("PASSWORD",Pass);
            return map;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Try put a breakpoint  and see if ur getting a respose.

Comment: http://blog.strv.com/debugging-in-android-studio-as/

Comment: @RissmonSuresh sir i didnt get you? can you explain?

Comment: Can you give the link to the api ? Is it on internet ?

Comment: what i meant is r u getting response as success??

Comment: are you getting any toast message?

Comment: @RissmonSuresh sir when i didnt use if statement and only put a Toastmessage inside like Toast.maketext(context,response,Toast.lengthshort).show; then i am getting toast message as success

Comment: that means whe you are using if, toast in your else is also not getting called?

Comment: @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
          
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
       }             ......if i am using only this then toast give message as success or failure

Comment: @MohammedAtif yes

Comment: Change equals to contains.

Comment: Ok. But now tell us why. Why did equals not work? Interesting.

Comment: @greenapps i dont know i am also searching  :-(

Answer (score 0):

As @greenapps noted in comments changing `.equals()` to `.contains()` work because in my case response was coming with double quotes, so "success"!=success but "success" contains success

Answer (score 0):

first of all check what response you receiving by debugging or by simply toast your response